# Fill a new column by a function that uses 2 existing columns with python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have some trouble creating and filling a new column based on 2 other row values. 
I created a function that finds (in a large CSV file (1GB)) the source and destination postal code and returns the specif row.

I want to generate the distance and time and add it as a new column in the orders file.

I tried it with orders.apply() than I get this error

```
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 88, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 128, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi", line 91, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
KeyError: ('customer_address', 'occurred at index datetime')
```

Another issue that I have is that the execution time for executing calculateDistance is 20 seconds. I am wondering if there are any performance improvements that I can make.

```
import pandas as pd

orders = pd.read_csv('ordersModified.csv', delimiter=';', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
distance_chunks = pd.read_csv('PostcodeDistances.csv', chunksize=100000)

def calculateDistance(src, dest):
    result = pd.concat([chunk[(chunk['src'] == src) & (chunk['dest'] == dest)] for chunk in distance_chunks])
    return result


orders['distance_meters'] = orders.apply(lambda row: calculateDistance(row['customer_address'], row['restaurant_address']).meters)

distance = calculateDistance("9727KE", "9742PA")
print(distance.meters)
print(distance.seconds)
```

orderModified.csv looks like this:

```
datetime;restaurant;customer_address;amount;restaurant_address
2018-01-01 09:01:48;Name;9728AC;59.93;9717BB
2018-01-01 09:02:13;Name;9712AN;110.73;9727KE
2018-01-01 09:02:52;Name;9732MC;22.30;9726BD
2018-01-01 09:03:21;Name;9743KX;63.98;9718CS
2018-01-01 09:03:59;Name;9721BJ;37.93;9726BD
2018-01-01 09:04:38;Name;9713JL;37.87;9728VJ
2018-01-01 09:05:03;Name;9728VD;70.07;9718CB
2018-01-01 09:05:45;Name;9721VW;75.32;9718CP
```

PostcodeDistances.csv looks like this (29.003.611 rows):

```
src,dest,meters,seconds
9728AC,9717BB,22.5,5.5
9711AA,9711AC,55.1,13.2
9711AA,9711AD,93.6,22.5
9711AA,9711AE,135.5,32.6
```

Comment: It would be easier to generate an answer if your `PostcodeDistances` example file would have some `src` and `dest` which are in your example `order` table, right now there are no matches.

Comment: @Erfan you're right, my apologies! Already changed the example file.

Comment: Is this right ```(chunk['src'] == src) & (chunk['dest'] == dest)```? Shouldn't it be ```(chunk['src'] == src) and (chunk['dest'] == dest)```?

Comment: @accidias the calculateDistance function is working fine. The main issue is that I don't know how to execute it in one propper query for creating and filling 2 new columns in the order file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest and fastest what you can do here is to `merge` (read: `join`) both dataframes on the deperature postcal code and arrival postal code. This way you get all the `meters` +  `seconds` information in your `order` dataframe in one go.

Code for test data provided:

```
orders.merge(distance_chunks, 
             left_on=['customer_address', 'restaurant_address'],
             right_on=['src', 'dest']).drop(['src', 'dest'], axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
             datetime restaurant customer_address  amount restaurant_address  meters  seconds
0 2018-01-01 09:01:48       Name           9728AC   59.93             9717BB    22.5      5.5
```

---

For your `chunks` it would look like this (can't test this myself):

```
dfs = []
for chunk in distance_chunk:
    dfs.append(
    orders.merge(chunk, 
             left_on=['customer_address', 'restaurant_address'],
             right_on=['src', 'dest']).drop(['src', 'dest'], axis=1)
    )

final_df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)

print(final_df.head())
```

Comment: Nice, I think this indeed the way to go! The only problem is that I get an exception during execution. https://ibb.co/8Xw91nq

Comment: The first answer I gave was just for your example data, this will not work for your real example since you've read your data using the `chunksize` argument, which does not return a dataframe. Please check my second answer, where we have to iterate over ever chunk in your `distance_chunk`, because these are dataframes. On these we can use the `merge` method @RobertZandberg